# Worklight to tomcat migration

Tags: tomcat7, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

Currently my UI code is running in worklight server(Version:6.0.2) and consuming SAP services through java servelet which is running in Tomcat(7.0.34).

How to migrate the UI code that is running on worklight server to Tomcat? The organisation is planning to stop using worklight.

Sample from existing code flow:

abc.js file: below code is inside an event triggered from UI

```
var invocationData = {
    adapter : 'EMDetailsMiddleLayer',
    procedure : 'getManagerDetails',
    parameters : [ searchParam, globalUserIdEM ]
};
```

Middlelayer.js:

```
function getManagerDetails(searchParam,globalUserIdEM)
{
        var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : 'TestEmployee/MovementServlet',
        parameters : {
            'action': 'getMgrDetails',
            'input' : searchParam,
            'pernr' : globalUserIdEM
        }
    };
    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

Empservelet.java

```
if (valuesFromUI.equalsIgnoreCase("getMgrDetails")) {

                String pernr = request.getParameter("pernr").toString().trim();
                pernr = pernr.replace(" ", "");
                strReqUrl = resourceConst.getString("SAP Url")
                        + "&pernr=" + pernr;
            }
```

How to migrate UI code (html and js) to tomcat?

Comment: Which JS framework are you planning to migrate? If it is angular, just replace the call http.post or get instead of adapter methods. Your API was supposed to return the same response structure otherwise it will break

Comment: Thanks for the response.I am not using angular,it is jquery.I am using ajax call to call the services and it is returning the response as expected.